# Getting an error on the if else statement when trying to get the value from a label and also a Boolean error invalid expression term

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have 3 textboxes that accept value from the user and on button click i calculate the total and the average. After that i would also like to print the grade but the value of the average in printed in textbox and i get an invalid expression error too " >= " and even if i use " => ". Thank you.

```
//print grade

        if (label14.Text = => 90)
        {
            label15.Text = "A";
        }

        else if (label14.Text = >= 80)
        {
            label15.Text = "B";
        }

        else if (label14.Text = >= 70)
        {
            label15.Text = "C";
        }

        else if (label14.Text = >= 60)
        {
            label15.Text = "D";
        }
        else
            label15.Text = "F";
```

Comment: You have `= => ` instead of `>=`. You write it as it is pronounced: "**greater than** or **equal**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that instead

```
    var mark = Convert.ToSingle(label14.Text);

    if (mark >= 90)
    {
        label15.Text = "A";
    }

    else if (mark >= 80)
    {
        label15.Text = "B";
    }

    else if (mark >= 70)
    {
        label15.Text = "C";
    }

    else if (mark >= 60)
    {
        label15.Text = "D";
    }
    else
        label15.Text = "F";
```

Comment: Why convert it 4 times?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming label14 is your textbox, label14.Text is a string.  You can't compare it to an integer without parsing.  At an absolute minimum, you need to use

```
int.Parse( label14.Text) >= 90
```

though validating the input as correct would go a long way to making the app usable.

Answer (score 0):

`label14.Text` is a `string`, where as `90` is an `int`!

It is always better to separate the logic from the UI. This enables you to concentrate on the very logic without having to deal with conversions textboxes and labels.

Write a separate class

```
public class GradeCalculator
{
    public string ScoreToGrade(decimal score)
    {
        if (score >= 90) return "A";
        if (score >= 80) return "B";
        if (score >= 70) return "C";
        if (score >= 60) return "D";
        return "F";
    }

    public decimal Total(IList<decimals> scores)
    {
        ...
    }

    public decimal Average(IList<decimals> scores)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In your form you can now convert the input like this

```
var calculator = new GradeCalculator();
decimal score;
if (Decimal.TryGetValue(label14.Text, out score)) {
    label15.Text = calculator.ScoreToGrade(score);
} else {
    label15.Text = "Please enter a valid number";
}
```

And it would make the code more readable if you gave your controls better names. E.g.: `scoreTextBox`, `gradeLabel` and `calculateButton`.